# Update column value that has one or more same values of other column

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have this statement:

```
UPDATE `tblAllocatedLeads` 
SET tblAllocatedLeads.fldAllocatedStatus = CASE 
WHEN tblAllocatedLeads.fldAllocatedStatus = 'Allocated' 
AND 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM `tblAllocatedLeads`) AS tblallocate WHERE AND tblallocate.fldAllocatedLeadId = tblAllocatedLeads.fldAllocatedLeadId) > 1 
THEN 'Outstanding' 
END
```

What I wanted is that update all rows where **fldAllocatedStatus = 'Allocated'** to 'Outstanding' that has one or more same value of column **fldAllocatedLeadId** to other rows.

my data

```
ID   fldAllocatedStatus   fldAllocatedLeadId
1    Accepted             123
2    Rejected             123
3    Allocated            123
4    Allocated            321
```

In this case **ID = 3** should update **fldAllocatedStatus** to 'Outstanding' as it has one or more same **fldAllocatedLeadId** from **ID = 1,2**

and **ID = 4** should stay 'Allocated' as it doesn't have match of **fldAllocatedLeadId** with other rows.

right now what it does it updates even the **"Accepted,Rejected"** which is supposedly to update only rows with **"Allocated"**

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any aggregation, just a self join:

```
UPDATE tblAllocatedLeads t 
INNER JOIN tblAllocatedLeads tt
ON tt.id <> t.id AND tt.fldAllocatedLeadId = t.fldAllocatedLeadId 
SET t.fldAllocatedStatus = 'Outstanding' 
WHERE t.fldAllocatedStatus = 'Allocated';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/twaQhKPpzpS1fZWmtRAot6/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | fldAllocatedStatus | fldAllocatedLeadId |
| --- | ------------------ | ------------------ |
| 1   | Accepted           | 123                |
| 2   | Rejected           | 123                |
| 3   | Outstanding        | 123                |
| 4   | Allocated          | 321                |
```

Comment: This one works very well as I wanted. Thank you very much!. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MySQL, I think you want:

```
UPDATE tblAllocatedLeads al JOIN
       (SELECT al2.fldAllocatedLeadId
        FROM tblAllocatedLeads al2
        WHERE al.fldAllocatedStatus <> 'Allocated'
        GROUP BY al2.tblAllocatedLeads
       ) al2
       ON al2.tblAllocatedLeads = al.tblAllocatedLeads
    SET al.fldAllocatedStatus = 'Outstanding'
    WHERE al.fldAllocatedStatus = 'Allocated' ;
```

The subquery gets leads that have some value that is  not allocated.  The outer `WHERE` only updates the allocated row (if there is one).